# Fixing a "Watery" beer

Tags: bottling, kegging, late-addition, body, mouthfeel

I brewed a V2 of [this NEIPA I was trying to improve](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/23118/debugging-a-bitter-ddh-neipa) and it's currently sitting in the keg awaiting bottling.

I brewed on new equipment and I had less boil off than expected so I had maybe a .75-1gal more sparge than I needed. I also tried a tablet of Whirlfloc to help with my sediment issues.

All of those things combined gave me a less hazy beer and has me worried about a watered down beer.

It's been carbonating at 30psi (room temp) for a week now and I'm ready to bottle. Should I even bother with trying to fix it?

I've read that adding half a pound of maltodextrin can help bolster the body but I'm not sure when to add it or if it is even the right choice. Do I portion it out per bottle?

Comment: what was your O.G and F.G? for this batch

Comment: SG: 1.052 FG: 1.01

Comment: Maltodextrin can add a little sweetness, and is usually added pre-fermentation.  How big was your batch? An extra gallon / 4 litres isn't a huge amount into a 5 gallon/19 litre batch, only ~ 20%.  It might not be what you were aiming for, but I think it'll be OK.  Especially given NEIPAs are a bit over-the-top to begin with.

Comment: 1.010 is a perfectly normal FG, I wouldn't worry about it, but do take notes and correct next time, if you still feel it's an issue.

Comment: 1.010 is normal but low in my book.  Perhaps next time you can play with mashing temperature to increase body.

Answer (score 1):

Carbonation level has a significant influence on mouth-feel.  You could try carbonating it up a bit further, maybe to 2.8 or 3.0 volumes of CO2.  Obviously this isn't going to "fix" everything.  This is a simple thing to try and is relatively easy to un-do (in a keg).

But you could probably should just leave it as-is.